# Build Logic Tree like the where clause in sql

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, logic, where-clause

I want to build a Logic Tree in Java which contains the conditions that could be used
for database insertions.

for example:

`Node tree  = input0.eq(3).and(input1.eq(1).or(input2.greaterThan(5)));`

could be converted to:

`WHERE input0=3 AND (input1 = 1 OR input2 > 5)`

Since a Node could be a logical expression like and,or etc. as well as a Leaf with data, I thought a parent Node class and two child classes, would be ideal. But I have no idea how to handle nested expressions. I already read a few similiar questions here, but they weren't really specific enough.

```
public class Node {
    public Long id;

    public Node parent;
    public List<Node> children;
}
```

```
public class LogicalNode extends Node {
    LogicType logicType;
    public LogicalNode () {
        super();
    }
    getter and setter...
}
```

```
public class LeafNode extends Node {
    Object input;
    public LeafNode () {
        super();
    }
    getter and setter...
}
```

```
public enum LogicType 
{
   AND("and"),
   OR("or"),
   NOT("not"),
   EQ("="),
   GREATER_THAN(">"),
   LESSER_THAN("<");

    private String name;

    LogicType (String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, try something similar to this:

```java
public abstract class Node {
   abstract void toSql();

   Node eq(Node other) { 
      return new LogicalNode(LogicalType.EQ, this, other);
   }

   ...
}
```

```java
public class LeafNode extends Node {
    LeafNode(int value) { 
        this.value = value;
    }

    String toSql() {
        return this.value.toString();
    }
}
```

```java
public class LogicalNode extends Node {
    LogicalNode(LogicalType type, Node left, Node right) { 
        this.logicalType = type;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    String toSql() {
        return String.format(
            "(%s) %s (%s)",
            this.left.toSql(),
            this.logicalType.getName(),
            this.right.toSql()
        );
    }
}
```

The key here is that the `LogicalNode` is constructed using two other `Node`s, but it doesn't concern itself with whether or not they are `LeafNode`s or `LogicalNode`s. All `LogicalNode` knows is that it has two things that can be converted to a string using `toSql`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm still not sure how to implement the and,or,not,eq, greatherThan and lesserThan methods. Do you have an idea? These methods needs to return a Node, since they can be nested in each other as my example shows.

Comment: Added more detail to the `Node` class in my answer.